# Google Map marker window custom design

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi I am new to Google maps. I am trying to customize the design of the `ui-gmap-window` inside google maps in angularjs. So far my effort are in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aY7fPivVPCSF3hB437b3?p=preview). **I am getting a result like**:

[image]

With extra space on right and default close button **(x)**.

**Whereas I am looking for a result like below:**:

Can someone have a look at my plunker code and guide me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the width and height from your `marker-holder` element you will  get rid of the scrollbars. But if you need a more custom layout, close button rounded corners etc you need to use a third party library for custom infowindows.

Comment: Nopes, removing width & height did not work in removing scrollbars.

Comment: Are you sure? I just removed the inline style and I had no issue. I will check it in a while ;)

Comment: You were right, that was strange. If I just remove the height and the width it works but if I try it in another window there is a problem.